# How write correct Regex for mobile number must start some from specific number or characters? MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, mobile, nsregularexpression

I want to enter only numbers staring from 92 0r 03. It should accept only 12 character if starting from 92 but it should accept only 11 characters if starting from 03. for example (92307XXXXXXX) or (0307XXXXXXX). I have written a regex but its now working. It says invalid number upon entering right format. Please help.

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number.")]
```

Comment: Please define the format you are trying to match ***clearly**, with examples,* and show some examples of inputs you have tried *and what result you got for them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This regex should do the job.

^(?:\+?92|0092)\d{10}$|^03\d{9}$
```

Comment: thank you. Can you explain why my logic didn't work?

Comment: First, you have inserted hyphens at multiple places and it's wrong because of no presence of hyphens in a telephone number. Then, your regex permits a wrong telephone numbers : `^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$` Behind 92 or 0092 you have inserted {0,1} so 92 or 0092 are facultative. So if I enter 040 (for example) followed by 7 digits it will match